# Comparison of String vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to compare to compare to String values.

```
 Dim tod As String = "04/02/2016_01:20"
 Dim DBookTo As String = "08/02/2014_01:30"
 If tod = DBookTo 
  'do something
 If tod<DBookTo
  'do something
 If tod>DBookTo
  'dosomething
 endif
```

Ideally I want here the 3rd condition to be executed because "08/02/2014_01:30" is smaller than "04/02/2016_01:20".
But the 2nd condition is being executed. Please help me here.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're performing string comparison, what means your input is compared char by char, until first difference is found.

First difference is on second character, between `4` and `8`. And because `4` is lower then `8` that's makes `tod` lower then `DBookTo`.

To make it work and really compare the values, not string representation you have to use proper type, which in your case is `DateTime`:

```
Dim tod As DateTime = New DateTime(2016, 2, 4, 1, 20, 0)
Dim DBookTo As DateTime = New DateTime(2014, 2, 8, 1, 30, 0)
```

You can also get `DateTime` instance from your string using `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
Dim todString As String = "04/02/2016_01:20"
Dim DBookToString As String = "08/02/2014_01:30"

Dim tod As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(todString, "MM/dd/yyyy_hh:mm", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
Dim DBookTo As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(DBookToString, "MM/dd/yyyy_hh:mm", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: >Thanks.
>Ok then can you please tell me how to achieve dBookTo < tod

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to compare dates. So instead of strings, you can use date variables. 
ex:
    `Dim dt1 as Date=#15/2/2014 8:00:00#`  
    `Dim dt2 as Date=#14/3/2012 6:00:00#`
    `if dt1>dt2`
    `'when dt1 comes later in the calender than dt2 (which is the case here)`
   `elseIf dt1<dt2`
     `'when dt1 comes before dt2`
    `else`
     `'when both are same`
    `end if`